# Determining .Net Framework at runtime from a library

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-7, c#-4.0

I'm somewhat new to .Net, so go easy on me ;-).  Anyway.

I working on my first WP7 library project which I hope will be compatible with both XNA and SilverLight applications.  Based on whether I'm in XNA or Silverlight one of my factory classes needs to load different config class. Whats the best way to determine this at runtime, from a library.

I know I could do this with the "SILVERLIGHT+WINDOWS_PHONE" preprocessor directives at compile time. But that would mean building two DLLs, which isn't ideal.

~Sniff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the information you're looking for can be found in the `Environment.Version` property or in the `OperatingSystem.Version` property.

Comment: This lead me in the right direction. Thanks.  Environment.OSVersion was what I needed.  On WP7 it returns (Microsoft Windows CE 7.0..).  And on XBox it returns something with Xbox.  In my case I was incorrect in thinking I need to know which framework I was on, as a coworker pointed out I only need to know which OS I was on.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could think of is setting up your library like so:

```
[Conditional(#XNA),
 Conditional(#WINDOWS_PHONE)]
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    var x = null;
    x = DoSomeXNAWork();
    x = DoSomeWP7Work();

    if (x != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}

[Conditional(#XNA)]
private ?? DoSomeXNAWork()
{
    return ??;
}

[Conditional(#WINDOWS_PHONE)]
private ?? DoSomeWP7Work()
{
    return ??;
}
```

Then, just make sure the project referencing this library has the directive set. Kind of like how Microsoft uses the Debug conditional classes such `Debug.WriteLine(...)`. I'm not sure how you could get it to use 2 different config files. I'm sure there is a way because when you create a new Web Project (ASP.NET) there is a config file that is split into Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config. I couldn't find an answer as to how to do it outside of ASP.NET though.